# Some good Sphinx customization examples?

Tags: python-sphinx

I've created a Sphinx document using **sphinx-quickstart**.

1. Are there any good examples/tutorials about customizing the look?  Specifically to modify the header and add a logo.
2. Are there some projects with downloadable Sphinx docs?  I would like to see how they've customized their look.

**update:** Adding a logo is supported in the default setup, just not particularly well documented.  Look in `conf.py` for the `*_logo` settings.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at some of [these themes](http://www.writethedocs.org/guide/tools/sphinx-themes/). As the projects are open source you should be able to examine them closely.

Comment: The one mentioned in comments. https://github.com/coordt/ADCtheme

Answer (score 10):

Time to start collecting links.

- https://github.com/coordt/ADCtheme   - Apple-like
- https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes - Flask
- http://loose-bits.com/2012/11/19/sphinx-bootstrap-theme-updates.html - Twitter Bootstrap
- https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme - Theme of Read the Docs
- https://github.com/bitprophet/alabaster - Based on the Flask
- https://gitlab.com/documatt/sphinx-themes - themes collection for tech writing

Answer (score 8):

[Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/) is an excellent example I think.  They even have a detailed description at [*documenting matplotlib*](https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/documenting_mpl.html): [dynamically generated figures](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/devel/documenting_mpl.html#dynamically-generated-figures) and [inheritance diagrams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/documenting_mpl.html#generating-inheritance-diagrams) are their custom extensions to Sphinx I think.  Their documentation has a custom logo too.

I would guess that you should be able to download the RST document source for most projects.

Answer (score 5):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ and http://ask.github.com/celery/ are two good examples.

Answer (score 4):

I've always liked the [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/index.html) docs. They look very different from the standard Sphinx themes and fit very well into their site.

Answer (score 4):

blender.org's new API Docs just got a makeover the sphinx theme is downloadable too

Site
 http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_release

Main Site (which theme is based off)
 [http://www.blender.org/](http://www.blender.org)

Theme files
https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/doc/python_api/blender-org/

Just one example I know, but interesting to see how close the match is.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the http://pypi.python.org and search for `sphinx template` there. It will give a list of some tens of templates. Then each of them You can download and try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [Kenneth Reitz](https://github.com/kennethreitz)'s theme he uses for the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/kr-sphinx-themes